# Multithread don't work in exe created by pyinstaller

Tags: python, django, multithreading, pyinstaller

**Problem:**

After changing to exe Thread not start. When i run in pycharm everything work properly.

**App info and sample code:**

My app mix django with custom app.

Django start by command: `.\myapp.exe runserver localhost:40218 --noreload`.

```
import os
import threading

import django
from django.core.management.commands.runserver import Command as runserver

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'rest_api.settings.base')
django.setup()
runserver.default_port = "40218"

from app.processes import start_processing  # noqa: E402
from app.threads_configuration import multiple_threads_creator_wrapper  # noqa: E402
from manage import main  # noqa: E402

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        ctx = ctx_manager()
        threading.Thread(target=multiple_threads_creator_wrapper, args=(start_processing,)).start()
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Application closed due to error: {str(e)}')
```

multiple_threads_creator_wrapper:

```
def multiple_threads_creator_wrapper(target, *args, **kwargs):
    LimitedThread(target=target, *args, **kwargs).start()
    RepeatedTimer(target, *args, **kwargs)
```

Thread config:

```
class Config:
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            self.maxThreads = 10
            self.runEveryXSeconds = 5  
    
    
    _config = Config()
    _threadLimiter = threading.BoundedSemaphore(_config.maxThreads)
    
    
    class LimitedThread(threading.Thread):
        def run(self):
            _threadLimiter.acquire()
            try:
                self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
            finally:
                _threadLimiter.release()
    
    
    class RepeatedTimer(object):
        def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
            self._timer = None
            self.interval = _config.runEveryXSeconds
            self.function = function
            self.is_running = False
            self.next_call = time.time()
            self._args = args
            self._kwargs = kwargs
            self.start()
```

Comment: first run .exe in console/terminal to see if it displays any error message. Without error message we have no idea what can make problem. `python` wasn't invented to create `.exe` and `pyinstaller` sometimes has problem to find and add all python modules. And some modules may need also C/C++ libraries which you may have to add manually to config file `.spec` when you run `pyinstaller. You should read `pyinstaller` for this.

Comment: you could use `logging` to write information which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - this way you can see what code is doing.

Comment: I found solution. 
The problem was that i don't run customized manage.py but run standard :D

Thx @furas i forgot to use logging and check if code is running.